# Not able to align imageview with respect to relative layout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-relativelayout

Following is the screen I am trying to design and I am using `CoordinatorLayout`
but not able to align my image along with `RelativeLayout` the way its shown in the screenshot.

[image]

following is my code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDocumentVerification"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layoutTitles"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutContent"
            android:background="@drawable/drawable_rectangle_white_grey_border"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgDocVerification"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_document_verification"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <com.widgets.TextViewRobotoRegular
                android:id="@+id/lblDocVerify"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgDocVerification"
                android:text="Document Verification"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@color/ekyc_black"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <com.widgets.TextViewRobotoLight
                android:id="@+id/lblUploadDoc"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgDocVerification"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lblDocVerify"
                android:text="Please upload your documents"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:textColor="@color/ekyc_light_gray"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <com.widgets.TextViewRobotoBold
                android:id="@+id/lblKnowMore"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgDocVerification"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lblUploadDoc"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:text="@string/know_more_about_sips"
                android:textColor="@color/color_view_history"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgExpand"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_crm_accepted"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/layoutContent"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Problem occuring to me is dropdown image not getting placed to the center of the horizontal line, but getting placed above that line. please help

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution for your problem. Instead of use Coordinator with nested Relative Layout, I use **LinearLayout** with nested **FrameLayout** and **LinearLayout**

This is the layout xml

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layoutDocumentVerification"
android:layout_below="@+id/layoutTitles"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgExpand"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_crm_accepted"/>
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutContent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDocVerification"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblDocVerify"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Document Verification"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblUploadDoc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Please upload your documents"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblKnowMore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Know more"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:textSize="13sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If you need a TextView with custom font, you should set **fontFamily** attribute in your custom theme.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to center your image because of "Document Verification" TextView if it is not in the center then you'll not able to set your image to center horizontal line.
You can check it first remove below line from "Document Verification" TextView

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgDocVerification"
```

Then center your image with below line. then you can set it in the center horizontal line.

```
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```